# Wifi on/off button on TP-Link WR841ND

Tags: wifi, openwrt, router

I installed OpenWRT into TP-Link WR841ND. Everything works as expected, but I can't get the wifi on/off switch working. I followed the guide described on [the OpenWRT page for this router](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr841nd#wifi.onoff.toggle.by.qss.button). Scripts in `/etc/hotplug.d/button/` simply don't get executed at all when I turn the switch on or off.

What could be the cause? Is there some package or kernel module missing?

My installed packages:

```
base-files - 117-r36088
busybox - 1.19.4-6
dnsmasq - 2.62-2
dropbear - 2011.54-2
firewall - 2-55.1
hotplug2 - 1.0-beta-4
iptables - 1.4.10-4
iw - 3.6-1
jshn - 2013-01-29-0bc317aa4d9af44806c28ca286d79a8b5a92b2b8
kernel - 3.3.8-1-d6597ebf6203328d3519ea3c3371a493
kmod-ath - 3.3.8+2012-09-07-3
kmod-ath9k - 3.3.8+2012-09-07-3
kmod-ath9k-common - 3.3.8+2012-09-07-3
kmod-cfg80211 - 3.3.8+2012-09-07-3
kmod-crypto-aes - 3.3.8-1
kmod-crypto-arc4 - 3.3.8-1
kmod-crypto-core - 3.3.8-1
kmod-gpio-button-hotplug - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ipt-conntrack - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ipt-core - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ipt-nat - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ipt-nathelper - 3.3.8-1
kmod-leds-gpio - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ledtrig-default-on - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ledtrig-netdev - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ledtrig-timer - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ledtrig-usbdev - 3.3.8-1
kmod-lib-crc-ccitt - 3.3.8-1
kmod-mac80211 - 3.3.8+2012-09-07-3
kmod-nls-base - 3.3.8-1
kmod-ppp - 3.3.8-1
kmod-pppoe - 3.3.8-1
kmod-pppox - 3.3.8-1
kmod-usb-core - 3.3.8-1
kmod-usb-ohci - 3.3.8-1
kmod-usb2 - 3.3.8-1
kmod-wdt-ath79 - 3.3.8-1
libblobmsg-json - 2013-01-29-0bc317aa4d9af44806c28ca286d79a8b5a92b2b8
libc - 0.9.33.2-1
libgcc - 4.6-linaro-1
libip4tc - 1.4.10-4
libiwinfo - 36
libiwinfo-lua - 36
libjson - 0.9-2
liblua - 5.1.4-8
libnl-tiny - 0.1-3
libubox - 2013-01-29-0bc317aa4d9af44806c28ca286d79a8b5a92b2b8
libubus - 2013-01-13-bf566871bd6a633e4504c60c6fc55b2a97305a50
libubus-lua - 2013-01-13-bf566871bd6a633e4504c60c6fc55b2a97305a50
libuci - 2013-01-04.1-1
libuci-lua - 2013-01-04.1-1
libxtables - 1.4.10-4
lua - 5.1.4-8
luci - 0.11.1-1
luci-app-firewall - 0.11.1-1
luci-i18n-english - 0.11.1-1
luci-lib-core - 0.11.1-1
luci-lib-ipkg - 0.11.1-1
luci-lib-nixio - 0.11.1-1
luci-lib-sys - 0.11.1-1
luci-lib-web - 0.11.1-1
luci-mod-admin-core - 0.11.1-1
luci-mod-admin-full - 0.11.1-1
luci-proto-core - 0.11.1-1
luci-proto-ppp - 0.11.1-1
luci-sgi-cgi - 0.11.1-1
luci-theme-base - 0.11.1-1
luci-theme-openwrt - 0.11.1-1
mtd - 18.1
netifd - 2013-01-29.2-4bb99d4eb462776336928392010b372236ac3c93
opkg - 618-3
ppp - 2.4.5-8
ppp-mod-pppoe - 2.4.5-8
swconfig - 10
uboot-envtools - 2012.04.01-1
ubus - 2013-01-13-bf566871bd6a633e4504c60c6fc55b2a97305a50
ubusd - 2013-01-13-bf566871bd6a633e4504c60c6fc55b2a97305a50
uci - 2013-01-04.1-1
uhttpd - 2012-10-30-e57bf6d8bfa465a50eea2c30269acdfe751a46fd
wifitoggle - 1-3
wpad-mini - 20120910-1
```

Kernel modules:

```
Module                  Size  Used by    Tainted: G  
ath79_wdt               2240  1 
ohci_hcd               16160  0 
ledtrig_usbdev          2032  0 
ledtrig_netdev          3184  0 
nf_nat_irc               784  0 
nf_conntrack_irc        2464  1 nf_nat_irc
nf_nat_ftp               976  0 
nf_conntrack_ftp        4416  1 nf_nat_ftp
ipt_MASQUERADE           976  1 
iptable_nat             2544  1 
nf_nat                 10256  4 nf_nat_irc,nf_nat_ftp,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat
pppoe                   7488  0 
xt_conntrack            2048  3 
xt_CT                   1216  0 
xt_NOTRACK               448  0 
iptable_raw              560  1 
xt_state                 608  0 
nf_conntrack_ipv4       4384  6 iptable_nat,nf_nat
nf_defrag_ipv4           656  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack           38336 12 nf_nat_irc,nf_conntrack_irc,nf_nat_ftp,nf_conntrack_ftp,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,nf_nat,xt_conntrack,xt_CT,xt_NOTRACK,xt_state,nf_conntrack_ipv4
ehci_hcd               33632  0 
pppox                   1152  1 pppoe
ipt_REJECT              1808  2 
xt_TCPMSS               2560  1 
ipt_LOG                 6160  0 
xt_comment               400  0 
xt_multiport            1104  0 
xt_mac                   528  0 
xt_limit                 944  1 
iptable_mangle           832  1 
iptable_filter           592  1 
ip_tables               8864  4 iptable_nat,iptable_raw,iptable_mangle,iptable_filter
xt_tcpudp               1632  4 
x_tables                9984 18 ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,xt_conntrack,xt_CT,xt_NOTRACK,iptable_raw,xt_state,ipt_REJECT,xt_TCPMSS,ipt_LOG,xt_comment,xt_multiport,xt_mac,xt_limit,iptable_mangle,iptable_filter,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp
ppp_async               5952  0 
ppp_generic            18848  3 pppoe,pppox,ppp_async
slhc                    4368  1 ppp_generic
ath9k                  84944  0 
ath9k_common            1152  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              329024  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    14320  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
mac80211              252240  1 ath9k
usbcore                99200  4 ohci_hcd,ledtrig_usbdev,ehci_hcd
usb_common               480  1 usbcore
nls_base                4640  1 usbcore
crc_ccitt                944  1 ppp_async
cfg80211              153696  3 ath9k,ath,mac80211
compat                  5776  5 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw,mac80211,cfg80211
arc4                     768  2 
aes_generic            29808  0 
crypto_algapi           9200  2 arc4,aes_generic
ledtrig_timer           1072  0 
ledtrig_default_on       416  0 
leds_gpio               1552  0 
gpio_button_hotplug     3184  0
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to OpenWRT 15.05.1 and after some fiddling this seems to work: I created a script in `/etc/hotplug.d/button/50-wifiswitch` containing

```sh
#/bin/sh
if [ "$BUTTON" = "rfkill" ] ; then
  if [ "$ACTION" = "released" ] ; then
    logger "Disabling wifi"
    uci set 'wireless.@wifi-device[0].disabled=1'
  elif [ "$ACTION" = "pressed" ] ; then
    logger "Enabling wifi"
    uci set 'wireless.@wifi-device[0].disabled=0'
  else
    logger "Unknown action: $ACTION"
    exit 1
  fi
  wifi
fi
```

Things to note:

- The button name is `rfkill`.
- It's actually a switch, not a toggle button, so the wifi state is determined by "pressed"/"released", not toggled.

Answer (score 0):

You probably hit this issue because hotplug is being replaced by procd package, more info and how to get button working is here:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/hardware.button

And please update the wiki when you get your buttons working.

Comment: I thought this is the problem too, but my version r36088 predates the switch to _procd_. The _hotplug_ package is present, but seems not to work.